# Find and Locate Current .profile

Tags: unix, user-profile, bash

How can I find and/or locate the file and directory of the currently loaded .profile in a bash shell.  I made modifications to the current .profile on my machine, and would like to update it some more.  I had created the current version in vi and couldn't tell where it was creating the file.

I am hoping that there is a command similar to "whoami"...

Answer (score 5):

Bash executes startup scripts in the following order if you start a **login shell**:

1. `/etc/profile`
2. `.bash_profile` under you home directory
3. `.bash_login` under you home directory
4. `.profile` under you home directory

And `.bashrc` under your home dir in case of **non-login shell**.

So, probably, you just have to run `vi ~/.profile`

Comment: Ah, found it in the home dir.  TY!